# git svn dcommit does not find changes and reset head

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a big problem with git-svn: I need to just push my git repo to a svn server, so I made the following

```
svn mkdir --parents http://host/path/to/repo/{trunk,tags,branches} \
    -m "Standard layout for $project"
git svn init -s http://host/path/to/repo/
git svn fetch
git rebase trunk master
git svn dcommit
```

This worked great and everything is both on git and svn!

Now I got the message that my git master branch is 31 commits behind the origin/master, so I made a git pull.
Now I changed some things in my repo (basicily its a eclipse java project) and commited it. Now I want also to push it on the svn repo and made a 
    git svn dcommit
but thats not working:

```
Committing to https://..../trunk ...
No changes
38b194cb2860b8bb73924cb05f9830dbdb70cf82~1 == 38b194cb2860b8bb73924cb05f9830dbdb70cf82
No changes between current HEAD and refs/remotes/trunk
Resetting to the latest refs/remotes/trunk
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       Product/Abgabe.tex
Unable to extract revision information  from commit daf483ad1333f3589386b87054f4c27fb7ff23cf~1
```

What I did wrong? The master is now reseted to the commit before, now I need to `git checkout -- Abgabe.tex` and `git pull` to have the right version here...

Edit: If I do a `git svn rebase`, I get for every commit a long list of CONFLICTS, so I made `git rebase --skip` to the end, and then dcommted, this was working, but it seems to be a bloody hack :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are missing in your work flow is `git svn rebase`
https://flavio.castelli.me/2007/09/04/howto-use-git-and-svn-together/

Comment: mh yes it seems so... ok then i identified the problem: if i use git on different hosts and push it to the repo and have to merge branches, the svn branch has a problem with the non-linear history. now i have to rebase... but thats pain in the ass! when i want to push to git again i need to pull first my git history and then rebase it again to the svn version...

Comment: I typically do a  `git svn rebase` on master then `git checkout -b feature_branch`. Do all my work in the feature branch once I'm ready to commit upstream to the svn server, I will `git checkout master` then `git svn rebase` then `git merge feature_branch` then `git svn dcommit`.

Comment: @Joe. Link is now broken, but git svn rebase was the trick. Thanks.